# How can I prove that $t\cosh(t)>\sinh(t)$ for $t>0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove this, in order to prove that the determinant of this matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}t&e^t-e^{-t}\\1&e^t+e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$$ 
 is linearly independent (when $t>0$).
I know that cosh is always bigger than $\sinh$, but what throws me of, is that t coefficient next to $\cosh(t)$, so I understand the trivial case of $t>1$, but I have no idea how to prove it for $1>t>0$.

Comment: Look at the power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(t)=t\cosh(t)-\sinh(t)$$ then we have $$f'(t)=t\sinh(t)$$, so we get $$f(0)=0$$ and $$f'(t)>0$$ for $t>0$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to show is that for $t > 0$ one has
$$\cosh t > {\sinh t - \sinh 0 \over t}$$
By the Mean Value Theorem, for some $0 < u < t$ one has
$${\sinh t - \sinh 0 \over t} = \sinh '(u) = \cosh u$$
Since $\cosh x$ is increasing for $x \geq 0$ one has $\cosh u < \cosh t$ as needed.

Comment: (+1){}{}{[{[{[{[}[

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It is equivalent to $\;t > \tanh t$ for $t>0$, and the hyperbolic tangent is concave for $t>0$, hence its graph is below its tangents on the interval $[0+\infty)$.

Guess  what the tangent at $0$ is?

Comment: $(+1)$ {[{}{}{}}9}}}}}

Comment: Thanks! What do these cryptic braces/brackets mean??

Comment: @Bernard I think they are extra characters to make comment at least 15 characters !

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put
$$f(t)=t\cosh(t)-\sinh(t)$$
for $t\ge 0$.

for $t>0$, by MVT, there exists $ c$ such that

$$0<c<t$$ and
$$f(t)=f(t)-f(0)=tf'(c)=t\sinh(c)=t\frac{e^{-c}}{2}(e^{2c}-1)>0$$